# Flutter download audio zip file and play in application

Tags: flutter, dart

Hello friend i am new in flutter i need help i have project where  almost different zip file hosted on sever every zip file have different audio with categories now  i want if user want to download that zip file and extract audio then able to play in application it not  visible in phone memory ?here example of code but this is for images and one zip file i take code from this url

https://www.coderzheaven.com/2019/06/07/download-zip-extract-it-and-show-the-images-file-in-list-in-ui/

here my code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:archive/archive.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
 
class DownloadAssetsDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  DownloadAssetsDemo() : super();
 
  final String title = "Download & Extract ZIP Demo";
 
  @override
  DownloadAssetsDemoState createState() => DownloadAssetsDemoState();
}
 
class DownloadAssetsDemoState extends State<DownloadAssetsDemo> {
  //
  bool _downloading;
  String _dir;
  List<String> _images, _tempImages;
  String _zipPath = 'https://coderzheaven.com/youtube_flutter/images.zip';
  String _localZipFileName = 'images.zip';
 
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _images = List();
    _tempImages = List();
    _downloading = false;
    _initDir();
  }
 
  _initDir() async {
    if (null == _dir) {
      _dir = (await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path;
    }
  }
 
  Future<File> _downloadFile(String url, String fileName) async {
    var req = await http.Client().get(Uri.parse(url));
    var file = File('$_dir/$fileName');
    return file.writeAsBytes(req.bodyBytes);
  }
 
  Future<void> _downloadZip() async {
    setState(() {
      _downloading = true;
    });
 
    _images.clear();
    _tempImages.clear();
 
    var zippedFile = await _downloadFile(_zipPath, _localZipFileName);
    await unarchiveAndSave(zippedFile);
 
    setState(() {
      _images.addAll(_tempImages);
      _downloading = false;
    });
  }
 
  unarchiveAndSave(var zippedFile) async {
    var bytes = zippedFile.readAsBytesSync();
    var archive = ZipDecoder().decodeBytes(bytes);
    for (var file in archive) {
      var fileName = '$_dir/${file.name}';
      if (file.isFile) {
        var outFile = File(fileName);
        //print('File:: ' + outFile.path);
        _tempImages.add(outFile.path);
        outFile = await outFile.create(recursive: true);
        await outFile.writeAsBytes(file.content);
      }
    }
  }
 
  buildList() {
    return Expanded(
      child: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: _images.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return Image.file(
            File(_images[index]),
            fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
 
  progress() {
    return Container(
      width: 25,
      height: 25,
      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 20.0, 10.0, 20.0),
      child: CircularProgressIndicator(
        strokeWidth: 3.0,
        valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.white),
      ),
    );
  }
 
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
        actions: <Widget>[
          _downloading ? progress() : Container(),
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.file_download),
            onPressed: () {
              _downloadZip();
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            buildList(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: have you tried with songs?

Comment: not yet do you know about it

Comment: you are downloading images or videos its not matter think for .zip file what you have inside of that zip file

Comment: code is in working condition just create your own *.zip with songs and its download and extract it

Comment: yes i got it but my issue is i have different zip file including audio and want get path of specific file also

Comment: ok, you wanted to know the path of the downloaded file.???

Comment: yes because after downloading file  want path of my file

Comment: because here is my scenario user play specific audio

Comment: _initDir() async {
    if (null == _dir) {
      _dir = (await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path;
    }
  }
this function show the dir of downloaded file 
print the _dir

Comment: ok and for example i have multiple zip file on server 1.zip 2.zip 3.zip user download 1.zip now they also want download 2.zip so how i can achieve this

Comment: you know what is file name right,
try to find it via folder name from same path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    _initDir() async {
        if (null == _dir) {
          _dir = (await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path;
          print("current dir--$_dir")
        }
      }
```

use like this